# Exception Access Violation in JRE

Tags: java, profiling, yourkit, java-mission-control

I am getting following exception sometimes while running a simple java application which doesnt uses JNI. I have used different versions like 1.6, 1.7.0_47 and 1.7.0_67 to check if it works fine with them. But it doesnt work. I am experiencing this problem once i have started using YourKit and Java mission control profiler.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006dd03db8, pid=7700, tid=7144
#
# JRE version: 6.0_39-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x443db8]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# hs_err_pid7700.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: Can you post a minimum example of the code that causes this?  Give use details about the command you are using to run your program, etc.

Comment: I am running it through eclipse with default java args by specifying a mainClass in that. Java is throwing this error at variety of places in different runs. I am running three different java applications and sometimes it doesn't work with all of them. I have tried resinstalling and installing java but this also doesnt help.

Comment: can you show portions of the code generating this error? also can you look in hs_err_pid7700.log and see what's in there?